# Source control with SharePoint?

Tags: svn, sharepoint, version-control, perforce

Have you tried to use SharePoint with version control such as Perforce (or Subversion), how did you do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you develop solutions for SharePoint using Visual Studio, there is nothing special if you are targeting SharePoint. All of your source files are handled as they normally are when you are using a version control system. I have used CVS, SourceGear and VSS successfully without any issues.

But since you are asking, I wonder if you really mean changes you are doing using SharePoint Designer?  Well, first, really consider switching over to developing your customization using features and solutions in Visual Studio instead. You have a much better control over the things you have modified, and I don't believe SharePoint Designer has support for source version control.

Comment: When you are using SharePoint designer to edit pages (assuming they are stored in a document library that has versioning turned on of course), you get basic versioning functionality too. Certainly nowhere near what you get when using Visual Studio though.

Comment: Agreed, just put all of your artifacts in Visual Studio. If I'm not working on a greenfields project I manually update the SharePoint Designer changes in my VS solution. It's annoying and prone to human error.